# distribution of the sum of two random variables convolution or not

Tags: probability

Given $$X_1\sim f_{X_1}(x_1)$$ and $$X_2\sim f_{X_2}(x_2)$$ are independent Random Variables, does this mean that $$Z=X_1+X_2$$ has distribution $$f_Z(z)\sim f_{X_1}f_{X_2} $$  or does it mean that the distribution is given by convolution of the two pdfs.

Comment: No. No. No. No. Convolution is the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The density of *the sum of* two continuous random variables is related to the joint density thusly:
$$f_{X_1+X_2}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, z-x_1)\operatorname d x_1$$

Independence means the *joint density function* is the *product* of the individual density functions.  This is *analogous* to the probability of the intersection of two independent events (aka the Product Rule).
$$f_{X_1, X_2}(x_2, x_2) = f_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot f_{X_2}(x_2)$$

Hence the density of *the sum of* two *independent*, continuous random variables is the *convolution*:
$$f_{X_1+X_2}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot f_{X_2}(z-x_1)\operatorname d x_1$$