# Question about a Symmetric random walk, Problem 4.1.1 in Durrett

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots \in \mathbb{R}$ be i.i.d. with a distribution that is symmetric about $0$ and nondegenerate, i.e. $P(X_i=0)<1$. Show that $-\infty = \liminf S_n < \limsup S_n=\infty$. Here $S_n=X_1 + \dots +X_n$.

I know that my two events are exchangeable and so by a corollary of the Hewitt-Savage $0$-$1$ law one of the following events occurs with probability one:

$
i) \ S_n=0 \text{ for all } n,
$

$
ii) \ S_n\rightarrow \infty,
$

$
iii) \ S_n\rightarrow -\infty,
$

$
iv) -\infty = \liminf S_n < \limsup S_n=\infty.
$

Since $P(X_i=0)<1$, $(i)$ cannot occur. I am pretty sure that if $(ii)$ holds then $(iii)$ must hold by the symmetry of the distribution and vice versa, which would be a contradiction. However, I cannot think of a mathematically precise way to say this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If $S_n\to\infty$ a.s. then for $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ s.t. for $n>N$, $P[S_n>1]>1-\epsilon$, say. But you know for any finite $n$, $P[S_n<0]=P[S_n>0]$ (E.g. induction. Given symmetric independent RVs $U$ and $V$, $P[U+V<0]=\int_x F_U(-x)dF_V(x)=\int_x(1-F_U(x))dF_V(-x)=P[U+V>0]$, ignoring continuity issues.)

Comment: I don't really understand your proof that $P(S_n>0)=P(S_n<0)$.

Comment: What part--are you familiar with induction and are you familiar with the formula (convolution) for the distribution of the sum of independent RVs?

Comment: I was not familiar with the formula, also I'm not sure what you mean by ignoring continuity issues

Comment: Arguing loosely, $P[U+V<\alpha]=\int_x P[U<\alpha-x \text{ and  }V=x] = \int_x F_U(\alpha-x)f_v(x)$ where $F_U$ is the cdf of $U$ and $f_v$ is the pdf of $V$. The inductive step is that given two symmetric RVs, their sum is symmetric. By ignoring continuity issues I meant I was not handling separately the cases where $U+V=0$ with positive probability.

Comment: Are you integrating over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes, integrating over $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Here is a related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141345/distribution-of-the-sum-of-two-random-variables-convolution-or-not but if you were proving this at the level of durrett you would not want to assume (as in my link) the RVs have lebesgue densities. It's a standard result though and should be in durrett (maybe in an exercise).

Comment: One more question, how do you justify this step: $\int_x F_U(-x)dF_V(x)=\int_x(1-F_U(x))dF_V(-x)$? How do you get the $-x$ in $dF_V(-x)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34215/discussion-between-snarfblaat-and-user112358).